# Minimising the distance covered

Tags: probability, puzzle

I am trying to solve the question: You are trying to get to go from A to B 10 times. At each journey, a coin is flipped and if its heads, a wall appears in the middle as in scenario 2. If tails, no wall appears. Construct a method to minimize the distance covered. What is the expected distance covered over those 10 walks?

[image]

**Attempt**: we can treat the 10 trials independently, and the expected distance of any one walk is 0.5 ( 2m) + 0.5 (4m) = 3m, so the expected total distance covered is 30 metres. But what strategy can we construct to minimize this distance? My only thought is to walk along the diagonals so that we are guareenteed to walk $2\sqrt{2}$ each walk, this minimizes the distance to approximately 28 metres.

Comment: $20$ meters.  Just keep flipping and walking until you get $10$ consecutive tails.  The question stated A to B $10$ times but didn't say only $10$ times so it may take $1000$ trips or so but eventually you should get $10$ consecutive tails.

Comment: Actually there is not enough information given.  What is the height of the wall?  Must the walker go around it?  Is the wall visible from point A?  When does the wall appear? Is the terrain flat?  We don't know what is along the diagonal there could be a big hill there.  Any other obstructions?  Many more unknowns too.  This is not a well phrased question.

Comment: These other answers seem wrong to me.  The wall is longer than 2m according to the diagram.  Also we don't know if the wall is perfectly perpendicular to the A B path/route.

Comment: @David this is math stack exchange, not nitpickery stack exchange

Comment: @Slungpue, I hope you don't ever build bridges or become an air traffic controller with that type of attitude.  The diagram clearly shows that the wall is more than 2m long and there are many other problems with the wording of this question.  I could easily reword this question so that it is clear so people don't have to state assumptions in their answers.

Comment: @David This is how I found the question, It was asked in an interview so I think they were looking for people to make their own assumptions as a way of testing their ability to solve a new problem

Comment: If you let people make their own assumptions then it becomes a "free for all".  I can assume the wall is made of tissue paper and I can walk right thru it.  I can assume the coin will come out tails 10 times in a row...   How would the interviewer know they were testing a "new" problem?  Maybe the person has already seen this problem before.

Comment: @David Well I'll be sure to bring this up to them if they end up asking me the same question

Comment: Part of math is clearly stating questions and answers.  This question is not clear and the answers make assumptions that may not be true and so far nobody else mentioned that the wall is longer than 2m but the diagram clearly shows that because the 2 line segments 1m long each do not touch, there is a gap between them, so anyone that answered this question assuming it is 2m long is wrong.

Comment: @David what do you mean? How is it longer than 2m?

Comment: You should have labelled the wall endpoints C and D and told us that distance is 2m then it would have been clearer but the way it is now, it appears to be about 2.1m.

Comment: @David are you for real

Comment: @David Some of the skills you need as a good mathematician is to understand the essentials of a problem and have the ability of abstraction. Someone with the ability of abstraction probably wouldn't start asking about whether the wall is solid or not..

Comment: To me it is not a question of abstraction, it is about accuracy.  I could have also assumed the wall was tall and solid so the walker must go around but that doesn't make me a better mathematician or even one at all.  If I asked this question, I would have clarified it and labelled it correctly.  The question is in my opinion, sloppy.

Comment: If you don't think accuracy is important, then why do they award points here on this math site for "correcting" and clarifying vague questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the coin is tossed each trip only upon reaching the wall position, and also that the diagram is a top view so we are walking around, not climbing over, the wall.

Firstly, the default expected distance should probably assume, in the case of tails, that you walk diagonally on the second part of the trip, so we would have $E(D) = \frac{1}{2}2 + \frac{1}{2}(2+\sqrt{2}) = 2+1/\sqrt{2}$.

The idea to walk the diagonal on the first half assumes the worst case (tails). There might be a middle ground that's optimal. Say you aim for a spot on the wall at distance $0\leq x\leq 1$ from its centre. Then the expected distance of one trip is

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(D) &=& \frac{1}{2} (2\sqrt{x^2+1}) + \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{x^2+1} + (1-x) + \sqrt{2}) \\
&& \\
&=& \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{x^2+1} - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
&& \\
\dfrac{dE(D)}{dx} &=& \frac{3x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}} - \frac{1}{2} = 0 \implies 3x = \sqrt{x^2+1}\implies x = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

With this value of $x$ we get $E(D)=\dfrac{6+\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}.\;$ And $10E(D) = \dfrac{30+5\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\approx 26.21$.

Comment: You are assuming a lot more than just that.

Comment: great answer, I didn't think of finding the optimal x, makes a lot of sense